# Создание словаря на python 2.7 работает правильно, но не работает на 2.6

Tags: python, python-2.x

Есть список имён файлов. Пытаюсь создать словарь на его основе, чтобы ключ был временем создания файла, а значение - именем файла.

```
import os

AllFileFull = ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt']

DictTimeFull = {os.path.getmtime(file_name):file_name 
                  for file_name in AllFileFull}
```

При запуске скрипта интерпретатор находит синтаксическую ошибку, хотя в IDE на python 2.7.5 ошибок нет и код выполняется.

```
# python test-script.py
  File "test-script.py", line 5
    DictTimeFull = {os.path.getmtime(file_name):file_name 
                      for file_name in AllFileFull}
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Вопрос - как переписать это место?

Comment: Старайтесь публиковать минимальный пример, на котором воспроизводится поведение

Comment: Спасибо, что поправили. Постараюсь следовать правилам.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Dictionary comprehensinons](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) (конструкции вида `{x.key:x.value for x in iterable}`, позволяющие лаконично создавать и заплолнять словари) были введены в Pyhton 2.7 для того, чтобы разработчики могли начать портирование кода на Python 3. В Python 2.6 такие конструкции не поддерживаются. Аналогом может служить цикл, заполняющий словарь:

```
DictTimeFull = {}
for file_name in AllFileFull:
    DictTimeFull[os.path.getmtime(file_name)] = file_name
```

Comment: Можно еще через `dict([(x.key, x.value) for x in iterable])` делать